# Extract a new vector of multiple mean values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, mean

I have a large data frame with multiple columns.
Two of my columns look like this:

`day_of_year <- c(123,312,23,123,322,1,23,321,124,192, ...)`

`group <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2, ...)`

I want to create a new vector with mean values of "day_of_year" for each group separated. Meaning my output vector should contain as many (mean) values as different groups in "group". Please note that some Groups have more values than others!

I hope you can help me with this one!

Comment: [This will probably help](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise) if you plan on learning R

Answer (score 0):

That's a case for `tapply`

```
day_of_year <- c(123,312,23,123,322,1,23,321,124,192)
group <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2)

tapply(day_of_year, group, mean)
#       1        2        3 
#145.2500 212.3333 115.3333
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be really helpful if you can post the end result that you are looking for, however, as per my understanding, if you are looking for a mean value per group, the following would work. (Install dplyr package)

```
install.packages('dplyr')
library('dplyr')

New.Data.Frame <- Your.Data.Frame >%>
                   group_by(,group)>%>
                    summarise(,Mean_Day_of_Year= mean(day_of_year ) )
```